# google maps not rendering on modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, modal-dialog

Below is my jquery code, I am rendering google map on a modal-popup using partial view.

Map not rendering itself, it render if I resize browser window or when I inspect my browser (same thing on window resize).

Also when it renders its not on center as per Latitude-Longitude set.

I want to render map dynamically based on Latitude-Longitude set from hidden fields. Currently I am passing Latitude=30.704648600 and Longitude=76.717872600.

I don't know what is missing please help, TIA.

**jQuery :-**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var currLoc;
        if ($('#Latitude').val().length > 0 && $('#Longitude').val().length > 0)
            initialize($('#Latitude').val(), $('#Longitude').val());
    });

    function initialize(Latitude, Longitude) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_'), {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 13
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            draggable: false,
            //anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude));

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        currLoc= $('#lastLocation').text();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' +
            '<div class="iw_title"><b>Last Location</b> : <span class="lastLoc">' + GetAddress(Latitude, Longitude) + '<span></div></div>';               
            infowindow.setContent(iwContent);               
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function GetAddress(Latitude, Longitude) {
        var LastLatLong = [];
        LastLatLong.push([Latitude, Longitude]);
        var latlngArray_ = LastLatLong[0];
        var latlngset_ = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngArray_[0], latlngArray_[1]);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlngset_ }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    //currLoc= results[0].formatted_address;
                    if ($('.lastLoc').length > 0) {
                        debugger;
                        $('.lastLoc').text(results[0].formatted_address);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Probably you are initializing your map when the div have no size (it have display none). Initialize it when the popup opens, or start -at page load-
 with the popup opened and hide it just after initializing. For this you coukld use opacity 0 on the begining, and change it to 1 after hiding it with display none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, it can be done by first triggering map's resize event, then use its setCenter property.

I changed my **initialize** function now its working fine.

```
function initialize(Latitude, Longitude) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_'), {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 13
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            draggable: false,
            //anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude));

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        currLoc= $('#lastLocation').text();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' +
            '<div class="iw_title"><b>Last Location</b> : <span class="lastLoc">' + GetAddress(Latitude, Longitude) + '<span></div></div>';               
            infowindow.setContent(iwContent);               
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
  setTimeout(function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude));
        }, 300);
    }
```